# Help with proof. Properties of the null space of unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

My understanding of how to prove things with null spaces is beyond limited.
I need help proving the following.

Given a unit vector
$$
\mathbf{x} \in \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ \vdots \\ x_{n}\end{bmatrix}
$$

where,
$$
\mathbf{Y} \in null(\mathbf{x}^{\top})
$$

such that,
$$
\mathbf{Y}^{\top}\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

show that 
$$
\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{\top} + \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\top} = \mathbf{I}
$$

In my case, $\mathbf{x}$ is a 3x1 column vector and $\mathbf{Y}$ is a 3x2 matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You must define what YY^t is.

Comment: $\mathbf x$ is a vector, and $\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top$ can be thought of as an operator, but $\mathbf Y$ is a *vector space*. While there indeed ways to interpret $\mathbf Y\mathbf Y^\top$, it would still be a set, not an operator like $\mathbf I - \mathbf x\mathbf x^\top$. Explain what you mean by $\mathbf Y\mathbf Y^\top$.

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm unsure how to properly reference a matrix that satisfies the null space of $\mathbf{x}^{\top}$. I hope the my edit clears things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that this is not true under the current hypotheses. Consider the real $3 \times 2$ matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}.$$ We have that $v = \langle 1, -2, 1 \rangle^t$ satisfies $v^t A = \langle 0, 0 \rangle$ and $A^t v = \langle 0, 0 \rangle^t,$ hence  $w = \frac 1 {||v||} v = \frac 1 {\sqrt 6} v$ is a unit vector satisfying $w^t A = \langle 0, 0 \rangle$ and $A^t w = \langle 0, 0 \rangle^t;$ however, it is not the case that $$AA^t + ww^t = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Explicitly, we have that $$AA^t = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 17 & 22 & 27 \\ 22 & 29 & 26 \\ 27 & 36 & 45\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } ww^t = \begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-} 1/6 & -1/3 & \phantom{-} 1/6 \\ -1/3 & \phantom{-} 2/3 & -1/3 \\ \phantom{-} 1/6 & -1/3 & \phantom{-} 1/6 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I agree that your counter-example disproves the hypothesis I originally posed. I didn't think was relevant to the problem at the time but my application is being implemented in Matlab which I just found out, by default, returns the $null(w^{t})$ in an orthonormal basis. I'm not sure whether I should start a new post with this added information or modify the original problem to include this. I'm at a loss for how to prove the problem considering this information, but thank you for the help @Carlo

Comment: Perhaps you could make a separate post with the updated hypotheses and a bit of background as to why you suspect this is true.